# Spring Boot freeze for ~ 4 seconds

Tags: spring, performance, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot to run a restful webapp. It should should handle 1000 request per second however I see that every ~100 requests the app takes about 4 seconds to return an answer. I'm using Spring boot version 1.4.4.RELEASE.

Comment: Is there some underlying resource that's saturated? IO/DB/something else? How about GC?

Comment: No. memory, disk, cpu etc. looks  ok.

Answer (score 4):

After attaching profiler to the JVM, I notice one of the tomcat threads is updating it's cache (org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache), increasing the cache ttl does however I don't see this issue in different versions of Spring boot.

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            final int cacheSize = 40 * 1024; // 40 mb
            final int ttl = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 min

            StandardRoot standardRoot  = new StandardRoot(context);
            standardRoot.setCacheMaxSize(cacheSize);
            standardRoot.setCacheTtl(ttl);

            // try this if the jar locks
            context.setResources(standardRoot);
            StandardContext standardContext = (StandardContext) context;
            standardContext.setAntiResourceLocking(true);
        }
    };
}
```

After upgrading Spring boot to 1.5.8 the issue is resolved.